# $k$-coloring in BPP, implies $k$-coloring in ZPP

Tags: complexity-theory, probabilistic-algorithms

Consider the next problem:

$k$**-COL**: Given a graph $G=(V,E)$, does it have a valid $k$-coloring?

I need to prove that if $k$**-COL** is  in **BPP**, then it is also in **ZPP**. In other words, show that if there is a probabilistic polytime algorithm that decides whether a graph has a valid $k$-coloring or not with bounded error, then there is also a probabilistic polytime algorithm that does that with zero error.

---

### My attempt

I've managed to prove it assuming that we are allowed to call an oracle that solves the above problem in polynomial time (see below).
But is there a way to show this without assuming $k$**-COL** $\in$ **P**?

Let $\mathcal{A}$ be a polynomial time machine with access to an oracle for $k$**-COL**.

Let $G$ be a graph and let $M$ be the **BPP** NTM that makes $k$**-COL** be in **BPP**. Let's define the following NTM $M'$:

If $G \in$ $k$**-COL**, execute $M$ on $G$.

1. If $M(G) = 1$, execute $\mathcal{A}$ on $G$. For sure, $\mathcal{A}(G)=1$.
2. If $M(G) = 0$, output $?$.

If $G \notin$ $k$**-COL**, execute $M$ on $G$.

1. If $M(G) = 1$, output $?$.
2. If $M(G) = 0$, execute $\mathcal{A}$ on $G$. For sure, $\mathcal{A}(G)=0$.

### Definitions (for reference)

We define the class of languages **Bounded-error Probabilistic Polynomial-time (BPP)** as all $L \subseteq \{  0,1\}^*$ for which there exists a NTM $M$ and $c \geq 0$ such that $t_M=\mathcal{O}(n^c)$ and that for all $x \in \{ 0,1 \}^*$:

1. $Pr[M(x) \in \{0,1\}] = 1$,
2. if $x \in L$, then $Pr[M(x) = 1] \geq 3/4$,
3. if $x \notin L$, then $Pr[M(x) = 1] \leq 1/4$.

We define the class of languages **Zero-error Probabilistic Polynomial-time (ZPP)** as all $L \subseteq \{  0,1\}^*$ for which there exists a NTM $M$ and $c \geq 0$ such that $t_M=\mathcal{O}(n^c)$ and that for all $x \in \{ 0,1 \}^*$:

1. $Pr[M(x) \in \{0,1,\text{?}\}] = 1$ and $Pr[M(x) = \text{?}] \leq 1/2$,
2. if $x \in L$, then $Pr[M(x) = 0] = 0$,
3. if $x \notin L$, then $Pr[M(x) = 1] = 0$.

Comment: If $\mathsf{k\text-COL \in P}$ then clearly $\mathsf{k\text{-}COL \in ZPP}$, so I don't really understand your question. Perhaps you should sketch your proof.

Comment: Are you sure you mean ZPP rather than, say, RP?

Comment: @YuvalFilmus Sorry, it was a typo. Corrected.

Comment: Can you copy the exercise you are trying to answer? I'm not sure that $\mathsf{NP} \subseteq \mathsf{BPP}$ is known to imply $\mathsf{NP} \subseteq \mathsf{ZPP}$, but it is known to imply $\mathsf{NP} = \mathsf{RP}$.

Comment: @YuvalFilmus Maybe the definitions I am using differs a bit from the definitions from Arora. I've written the notation I am actually using.

Comment: Your definitions are perfectly standard. Perhaps you could show your work?

Comment: @YuvalFilmus This is my work, but in fact is assumign that **k-COL** $\in$ **P**.

Comment: Your work doesn’t make much sense. Once you’ve determined whether your graph is $k$-colorable, you already know the answer. There’s nothing more to do.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This statement is to my knowledge unknown. If this is an exercise, then it is likely an error: did they mean $RP$ instead of $ZPP$?

Since $k$-coloring is NP-complete, what you are asked to show is:

> If $NP \subseteq BPP$, then $NP = ZPP$.

First, let's review what is known: the basic inclusions are the following:
\begin{align*}
P \subseteq ZPP \subseteq RP &\subseteq NP \\
P \subseteq ZPP \subseteq coRP &\subseteq coNP \\
                          RP &\subseteq BPP \\
                          coRP &\subseteq BPP.
\end{align*}

That is, $P$ is contained in $ZPP = RP \cap coRP$, which is contained in $BPP$. Moreover, $RP$ is contained in $NP$ and $coRP$ is contained in $coNP$.
But we don't know how $NP$ and $coNP$ relate to $BPP$ (it is conjectured that $P = ZPP = BPP$, which implies that $NP$ and $coNP$ contain $BPP$).

Now, what happens if (as in your exercise) $NP \subseteq BPP$? It follows (and is a common exercise to show) that
$$
NP = RP.
$$

(see e.g. [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BPP_(complexity)#Complexity-theoretic_properties)).
That means that
$$
coRP = coNP \\
ZPP = NP \cap coNP \\
$$
So basically in this case, we have $P$, which contains $NP$ and $coNP$, and those are both contained in $BPP$ (which also equals the polynomial hierarchy $PH$).

But there is no reason to believe that this implies that $NP = coNP$, which is what you would need to then show that your $NP$-complete language, $k$-col, is in $ZPP = NP \cap coNP$. In particular, we can imagine that $BPP$ is equal to the second level of the polynomial hierarchy (you don't need to be familiar with this, but it's just some level that contains both $NP$ and $coNP$). That would imply that $NP$ is contained in $BPP$, but it doesn't mean that $NP$ and $coNP$ are equal.

**TL;DR** The statement you are trying to show appears to be unknown.